# How to find out what application wants access to the default keyring

Tags: gnome, gnome-keyring

I've just installed 19.04 with Gnome, and am now finding on every startup I get a popup asking for access to the default keyring for "an application". I'm reluctant to give access to some unknown application, as this is not exactly good security protocol. How can I find out which application is requesting access, so that I can figure out if it is something I put there as opposed to a keylogger that someone else has gotten past my shaky security?

Because the application is unknown, I don't supply the password. Nothing seems to be broken or not working. Would there be a log somewhere where Gnome logs that which application requested access and was refused?

Just for the record, I think the fact that this popup does not give any information on the source of the problem is a security issue of Microsoft proportions.

[Security Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmM1t.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that your account has auto-login feature off. Auto-login may cause this.

You should find your login.keyring then in ~/.local/share/keyrings/:

```
ls -al ~/.local/share/keyrings/
```

If that is not the case, then you may try to find it out indirectly.

When prompted, try to grep journal for keyring entries:

```
journalctl -b | grep keyring
```

Eventually you may use lsof to find open file descriptors, linked to anything keyring-related:

```
sudo lsof -n | grep keyring
```

But keep in mind that "an application" doesn't implies that this popup is directly associated with an unknown app. It's rather generic for default login keyring.

Comment: Thanks, Comar. What you said give me some really valuable information about probing the journal. I'm a little confused about why I should turn off auto-login, though. I do have auto-login on, and I'm fairly certain the problem is occuring because it's the default keyring being access, rather than my login keyring. However, the purpose of the question is figure out which application is creating the popup not to make it go away, as it is really bad practice to simply assume it is going to be the last one installed, or to make any assumptions at all. I

Comment: I should've said: `if` you have auto-login, then you should disable it. And indeed, your suspicion is right and it's always better to be sure that nothing nasty is going on.