# Default Keyring request Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: permissions, password

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04.1 I keep getting these annoying "an application is requesting access to your default keyring" requests and asks me to authorize it by password. What is the purpose of this function if it does NOT identify the item asking for permission? How could one determine if they want to grant permission or not if they have no idea what is requesting access to this keyring? So why bother asking for permission?  How do I fix this or is Ubuntu working on repairing this issue?

Comment: Is this link useful? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138754/how-to-find-out-what-application-wants-access-to-the-default-keyring

Comment: The link was not useful. I do have some feedback from something I tried that does help. I switched from automatic log on to requiring a password from a user at startup and that  does eliminate the issue. Perhaps that can help Ubuntu arrive at a fix. It was easier for my wife to have auto logon since there is not an issue of security with just the two of us here. I would rather key in a password once per session than 15 times a minute with no avail.